# IoT device management/onboarding with Google Firebase

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, iot

I'm looking for something like AWS's device management functionality (https://aws.amazon.com/iot-device-management/) that exists on Google's Firebase service.

I found this: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-iot-firestore-config

But I'm not sure if I can achieve the same functionality as with AWS IoT Device Management (I'm still new to Firebase).

Is there a Firebase equivalent to AWS IoT Device Management, specifically regarding onboarding and organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent in Firebase.

Comment: @akr Correct me if I'm wrong, but the question is seeking either a "yes" or a "no".  The answer is definitely "no".  Do you have a suggestion of what kind of clarifying question would be more appropriate?

Comment: My feeling is that "yes" / "no" answers would be more appropriate as a comment, not an answer. An "no" answer should provide, for example, a work around. Don't you agree?

Comment: @akr My feeling is if the question can only be answered as a comment, then why is it a valid question at all?  How would the question be finalized with a canonical answer?

Comment: I really don't have have a strong opinion about this. If there is no work-around or alternative then obviously this is the final answer. It would just a bit more helpful with showing a solution. Anyway, I will remove my review.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, no, there's nothing directly in Firebase.

Have you looked at [Cloud IoT Core](https://cloud.google.com/iot-core)? It has a lot of the features you're probably looking for in a device manager. From there, there are data pipeline tools (like Google Cloud Functions, or Cloud Dataflow) which can ferry the telemetry data from your devices into Firebase (or, potentially a better option, Firestore).

I did a session at the Google Cloud Next conference this year (2018) which talked about the end-to-end IoT application, and we published the code we built on stage which includes IoT device management, and used Cloud Functions to push the data into Firestore if you're interested. Link can be found [here](https://github.com/GabeWeiss/GoogleIoTCoreApp). The Cloud Functions that moved the data into Firestore are in the gcf folder. The device folder has the Python code we used on device to send telemetry up to IoT Core.